# parsing error in yml file for microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

18:01:39.008 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 16, column 16:
uri: lb://USER-SERVICE

`

```
server:
  port: 9190


spring:
  application:
    name: API-Gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user-service
          uri: lb://DEPT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - path=/user/**
        - id: dept-service
            uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
            predicates:
              - path=/departments/**
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yaml is not valid. Check [this validator](http://www.yamllint.com/) as example.

Note how on line 16 and next, `uri`, `predicates` and `path` are not on the same column as just before.

Valid yaml is:

```
server:
  port: 9190


spring:
  application:
    name: API-Gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user-service
          uri: lb://DEPT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - path=/user/**
        - id: dept-service
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - path=/departments/**
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```